# How can be used returned temporary link in best way?

Tags: c++, c++11

- for example I have

  ```
  class A {
       AHelper&& getAHelper(){
           return AHelper();
      }
  }

  int otherfunc(){
      A a;
      xfunc( a.getAHelper() );
  }
  ```

  May I use it only if I want to pass it to another  function? What are benefits?

Answer (score 3):

Return by value.  Any attempt to return a temporary by reference...ANY kind of reference...is going to end in tears.

Comment: I don't even know how you comprehended the question enough to answer it.